# GitHub Security Logs

Tags: git, github

I recently logged in to github and looked at the security history, which is on the settings page. In my security there are instances of sessions being established with actor_ips that map to a geographical location that is far away from any location that I have logged in at. How does github collect these IPs? Should I be worried if these IPs map to a different location than my current one?

Comment: Could you mean GitHub instead of git?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for catching that. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the GitHub servers they have to send data back to you.

They get your current IP when you connect to GitHub (in order to answer back).

I am not sure how they map IPs to geolocation, but there are several services around (simply google for "IP to geolocation").

The quality of the geolocations detected depens on the quality of the database as well as the IP (I think there are some that are easier to locate than others).

Just in case you could change your password an enable two-factor-authentification to be safe.

In case you are using some VPN or other means to obfuscate your IP those addresses might actually be you.

Hope that helps